# Kubernetes adding the name of the pod as a label

Tags: kubernetes

I need to add the name of a kubernetes pod as a label to that pod when I create a pod using a replication controller. Is there a way to do that or should I do a patch once the pod is created?

Comment: RC does not add the pods name as a label.  Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, so maybe we can find a different approach?

Comment: I want to create a service per pod. In that case I need to uniquely identify the pod in the selector of service. I hope to use the name of the pod as the selector for service.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to auto-promote the pod name into a label.  You'll have to do that manually.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, a headless service may work for you:
http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html#headless-services

Specify spec.clusterIP=None

DNS is ten configured to return multiple A records (addresses) for the Service name, which point directly to the Pods backing the Service.

Otherwise, you may want to follow progress on the PetSet proposal:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18016